# How to string or work with textbook style math in java

Tags: java

I want to string math as it is in textbook using java. Please help me with the best option to do this. The code is just for the idea. Thanks

```
package app1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tasnim {
    public static void main (String[] args){

double a,v=4,u=0,t=7;
    a=(v-u)/t;
        System.out.println("       "+"v - u");
        System.out.println("a = —————————");
        System.out.println("         t");
        System.out.println("   ");
        System.out.println("     "+v+" - "+u);
        System.out.println("a = —————————");
        System.out.println("        "+t);
        System.out.println("   ");
        System.out.println("        "+(v-u));
        System.out.println("a = —————————");
        System.out.println("        "+t);
        System.out.println("   ");
        System.out.printf("a =%9.4f\n",a);
        System.out.println("   ");
    }
}
```

Here i use 3 print method for a single line output. I also want to use mathematical symbol as '÷' and '×' etc. Any site or link or any idea where i can find the solution.

```
/* Output example.
run:
       v - u
a = —————————
         t

     4.0 - 0.0
a = —————————
        7.0

        4.0
a = —————————
        7.0

a =   0.5714  */
```

Comment: Do you only want to print fractions nicely? Do you intend to add integrals later, and matrices, superscript, subscript? How should square roots look like? Do you want to print fractions of fractions as well? Does it have to be plain text, or should it rather be in a GUI? Please [edit] the question to add these missing details.

Comment: everything should looks like as in textbook. yes i also want to print fractions of fractions as well. I should try plain text first.

Comment: If youjust want to get beautiful results without investing 2 years of your life, you should go with MathJax. It's not plain text though.

Comment: Use TeX! There's plenty of options. Typesetting is not easy.

Comment: Yeah TeX was helpful. Thanks @BoristheSpider

Answer (score 0):

Without external libs you hardly be able to avoid line by line printing, but can make it less concatenative. `String.format` or `System.out.printf` have a lot of nice formatting abilities which can help in simple cases ([java.util.Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)). There are also very skilled formatters for numbers in Java API.

For special symbols try to find the proper `code page`. Here are [list of symbols](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a.htm) and [supported encoding list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html). 
Have no precise answer for the dvision sign, but the general idea is to use `\u` characters:

```java
char c = '\u0025';
String s = new String(new byte[]{(byte) c}, Charset.forName("Cp850"));
System.out.printf("%c", c);
```